# Binding combobox, getting returned value and saving it to Database coded in C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm struggling with this problem for a week and I have searched everywhere, but could not figure out an answer myself. I have done half of it from clues on here but could not complete it.
What I want to do: I want to bind one or two fields to my combo boxes(one or two column combo). each field of these combo fields have an ID which is a FK in my profile table in my DB. DB is an entity framework Model first[.edmx](Auto code generated). I have connected to my DB like this:

**DataAccess:**

```
    #region Fields

    MedManAgeDbEntities objDataContext;
    readonly List<Patient_Profile> _patientsList;
    readonly List<Renal_Function> _renalFunctionsList;

    #endregion // Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new repository of patients.
    /// </summary>
    public PatientProfile()
    {
        objDataContext = new MedManAgeDbEntities();
        _patientsList = objDataContext.Patient_Profiles.ToList();
        _renalFunctionsList = objDataContext.Renal_Functions.ToList();
    }

    #endregion // Creation

    #region Public Interfaces

    public ObservableCollection<Renal_Function> GetRenalFunction()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Renal_Function> temp = new ObservableCollection<Renal_Function>(objDataContext.Renal_Functions.ToList<Renal_Function>());
        return temp;
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    #region Fields

    RelayCommand _saveCommand;
    readonly PatientProfile _patientsList = new PatientProfile();
    readonly Patient_Profile tempPatient;
    public ObservableCollection<Renal_Function> _renalFunction;

    #endregion //Fields

    #region Constructor

    public patientCharacteristicViewModel()
    {
        tempPatient = new Patient_Profile();
        _renalFunction = _patientsList.GetRenalFunction();
    }

    #endregion //Constructor

    #region Getters and setters

    public ObservableCollection<Renal_Function> RenalFunction
    {
        get
        {
            if (_renalFunction == null)
                _renalFunction = _patientsList.GetRenalFunction();
            return _renalFunction;
        }
        set
        {
            _renalFunction = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RenalFunction");
        }
    }

    #endregion //Getters and setters
```

**Veiw:**

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="14,0,-69,0" Width="234" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding RenalFunction/Level}"/>
```

Each Renul Function has attributes:ID,Level,Definition which ID is int and the rest are strings. When I click one of these levels on combo box I want to return the ID for that level and put it in patient.Renul_Function_ID. How do I do that?
After that, if I want to bind my Level and information into two column combo. what I have to do?

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding RenalFunction.Level}` - that's a typo?

Comment: No,it is not! that how it is...And it is working. I think it has changed a little bit from VS2010 and VS2012, this is VS2012.